# Adding Easing Effect /Animate() to Paper Image in Raphaël.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, raphael

Using Raphaël.js I am trying to add easing effect(animate) to newly added image into the pager. Here is the code I have for adding the image to the paper:

```
$("#change").on("click",function(){
    image2.remove();
    image2  = map.image('http://image2.png', 0, 0, 500, 500).insertBefore( circle );
});
```

and [This Is The Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/zalun/4MzNS/) that Raphaël is animating the svg(s)

```
this.animate({cx: this.cx, "stroke-width": this.cx / 100, fill: this.cx - 100 ? "hsb(0, .75, .75)" : "#000", "fill-opacity": +!!(this.cx - 100)}, 1000);
    this.cx = this.cx == 300 ? 100 : 300;
});
```

now my question is how I can use the same animate() in inserting image into the paper? Can you please let me know how to figure it out?

Thanks

> Update

```
$("#change").on("click",function(){
    image2.remove();
    image2  = map.image('http://image2.png', 0, 0, 500, 500).insertBefore( circle ).animate({ opacity: .2, x: 400 }, 1000, mina.easein) ;
});
```

Comment: In the first example, you are loading a png file. In the second its creating svg elements/objects (of which attributes are easy to play with). What exactly (ie what attributes) are you wanting to animate (and ease) of which image ? It makes a big difference, as you are limited what you can do with just a loaded png file.

Comment: Hi lan , sorry for confusion, As you remeber from my last question I would like to enable user to change the background image (Here image2) from a click handler (or even Select Options). As you helped me the function is working great but I just need to add some effects to the image when changing. For example instead of poping up all of a sudden, having easing from left to the final location like the First example at Raphaël easing examples. Once again thanks

Comment: Ideally you want to change the initial state (of x and opacity or something), within the svg and then animate when loaded. So you could add .animate({ opacity: 1, x: 400 }, 1000, mina.easein)

Comment: @lan, can you please take a look at update part of the above code? I update the function as the way you said but no animation added the event. No error message either. Can you please let me know if I am doing some thing wrong?

Comment: Hi again lan, I figure it out how this is working by adding the svg snap library to fiddle.This is the exact animation which I was talking for but I do not want to animate image from x =0 to x =400. What I want to do is animating from something like -100 to x=0.(Because I need to keep the image at exact location which was initially added as image('http://image2.png', 0, 0, 500, 500). Can you please let me know how to fix this?

Comment: .insertBefore( circle ).animate({ opacity: .2, x: 400 }, 1000, '>') (Snap uses mina.easein, but I think Raphael uses '<' and other easing)